# Cannot modify maintenance plan in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm running several Maintenance Plans on my SQL Server 2008 SP1 Standard installation. I'm running SQL Server Management Studio on both my development machine and a copy of it on the server. On either box, if I try and modify any of the existing Maintenance Plans or select "New Maintenance Plan...", nothing happens.

The only solution that I've seen for this was in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/769cc0a3-014f-45bf-baba-04e1ddf6179e) which suggested updating your install to include "Management Tools Complete" instead of Basic, but that option isn't available on my install screen. I'm guessing this is because I'm running Standard and not Enterprise. Note that this feature used to work so I know it's not a limitation of Standard Edition. I can't say for sure when it stopped working, but I believe the last time I used it was pre-SP1.

Comment: Wow. Must have stumped you guys.

Comment: I believe this is because you do not have the integration services installed. I have the same problem and have not resolved it yet.

Comment: I have the same issue. Maybe someone have found solution?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Management Tools Complete should be an option for both Standard and Enterprise. Are you sure you are running the installation for Management Studio and not Management Studio Express (which is the only case I know of that only allows Basic)?

Comment: This link shows how you first uninstal 'basic' and then installs 'complete'. It also shows how to check what version you are running. [http://paulgrevink.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/ms-sql-2008-r2-issue-impossible-to-modify-a-maintenance-plan/](http://paulgrevink.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/ms-sql-2008-r2-issue-impossible-to-modify-a-maintenance-plan/)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue to yours that was fixed by completely removing management studio and reinstalling it. It turned out that the problem was caused by a compatibility patch that Microsoft provides for DTS packages (post sql 2000).

The patch seems to break anything that uses SSIS (as maintenance does).

Answer (score 0):

This could also be permissions on the folder where these plans are stored....

e.g. c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\JOBS

I browsed to it directly and did not initially have permissions.   Explore prompted me this and asked for permissions.  After that I could view the contents (it had nothing) and then was able to save from SQL Manager.

Note: (I'm on Windows 2012 R2 with SQL 2014 and a local admin in this case)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem before and can be solved using different methods. This could be caused by several issues like using different version of management Studio than the SQL Server engine, error on registering dts.dll. So first try to identify what is the cause in your case then you might try the following technique.

1. Change the management studio to similar version.
2. Using CMD register regsvr32 dts.dll. first go to the Binn folder 
   CD C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn then exec regsvr32 dts.dll  NB. Make sure to choose the physical location can be different depending on the version in my case <120\DTS\Binn   > for sql server 2014 and can be 100\DTS\Binn   or 110\DTS\Binn   for sql server 2008 and 2012 respectively.
3. If the above 2 solution didn’t solve the issue, change your connection string and use a fully qualified domain name with the port number. 
   Example: servername.domainname.local\instancename,portnumber